# Using PHP in HTML files - an uncommon way

Tags: php, html, variables

I've seen several scripts during my time as a web programmer (I'm still new though) which had PHP included in an uncommon way.

The PHP was not added the usual way like `<div><?php echo $foo; ?></div>`, but this way: `<div>{FOO}</div>` or this `<div>{$foo}</div>`.

I am wondering how I could achieve such a thing? I really want to learn this thing.

Can someone direct me to the correct sources to learn this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to be a template engine? You inject values to it from a PHP script. [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) is a basic example.

For example, from your PHP page, you write :

```
 include('Smarty.class.php');
 $smarty = new Smarty;
 $smarty->assign('foo', 'Bar Baz');
 $smarty->display('index.tpl');
```

And, your template page would look like

```
 <div>{foo}</div>
```

with .tpl extenstion.

When the program is run, the template variable {foo} will be replaced by its assigned value "Bar Baz"

Comment: Does it have to be .tpl at any cost? :S

Comment: @Dugi- I don't think so. Just generalized in the context of smarty :-)

Answer (score 2):

The Developer must have been using a Template Engine Such as [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)

You can even define arrays:

```
{assign var=foo value=[1,2,3]}
```

Objects

```
{$foo->bar}
```

The following would help you get started

- http://www.9lessons.info/2011/09/smarty-template-engine-using-php.html
- http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/255552-an-introduction-to-smarty-php-template-engine/
- http://www.moskalyuk.com/blog/smarty-faq
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5xLfvY8upsQ (Video)